# Problem with 2D dynamic allocation of arrays and passing it as parameter

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following problem:
I am populating a 2D array whose number of rows is the number of files I am reading.  Therefore the number of columns in each row corresponds to the bytes of data read from the file.

With this picture in mind I have the following program:
I have to return a byte array of data read from each file and the size of each file. This is what I have:

```
void fillArrays(unsigned char **array, size_t dataSize[], int *nFiles)
{
    printf("Calling fillArrays\n"); 
    int i, j, nrows;
    nrows = 3;
    *nFiles = nrows; // assuming no. of files to be read = 3

    dataSize = (size_t *)malloc(nrows * sizeof(size_t));
    array = (unsigned char**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(unsigned char *));

    dataSize[0] = 4; // assuming file 1 contains 4 bytes
    dataSize[1] = 3; // assuming file 2 contains 3 bytes
    dataSize[2] = 1;// assuming file 3 contains 1 bytes

    //populating file data into a 2D array. Here for test purpose assuming each file has data = 0x03!!
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc(dataSize[i] * sizeof(unsigned char));
        for(j = 0; j < dataSize[i]; j++){   
            printf("round %d %d\n", i,j);
            array[i][j] = 0x03;
            printf("array [%d][%d]  = %02X\n ", i, j , array[i][j]); 
        }
        //array[i][dataSize[i]]= '\0';

    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char **fileArray;
    int noFiles = 0;
    size_t *fileSize;

    fillArrays(fileArray,fileSize, &noFiles);
    printf("Returned no. of files = %d\n", noFiles);
    printf("fileSize[0] = %lu\n", fileSize[0]);
    printf("fileSize[1] = %lu\n", fileSize[1]);
    printf("fileSize[2] = %lu\n", fileSize[2]);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <  noFiles; i++){
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        for (int j = 0; j <  fileSize[i]; j++){
            printf("Obtained data from file %d :  (fileArray [%d][%d])  = %02X\n ", i, i, j , fileArray[i][j]); 
            //j++;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

the code is segfaulting in the 'j' loop in the main function. Could someone throw some light? 
How can this be done better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `fileArray` by value, so in `fillArrays` you are modyfing copy of this pointer to pointer, so after executing `fillArrays` function, `fileArray` in main function is not affected - it is still uninitialized, you need to pass this variable by *reference* (pass pointer to `fileArray`):

```
fillArrays(&fileArray,fileSize, &noFiles);
```

then in `fillArrays` you need to add these modifications:

```
void fillArrays(unsigned char ***array, size_t dataSize[], int *nFiles)
{
    //...
    *array = (unsigned char**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(unsigned char *));
    //...
        (*array)[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc(dataSize[i] * sizeof(unsigned char));
    ///...
            (*array)[i][j] = 0x03;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In case I keep the function prototype as such, how can I "copy" the array when the function returns from fillarray to main?

Comment: @tweetlilly I guess you don't want to use `***` ? so declare your function as `unsigned char** fillArrays(size_t dataSize[], int *nFiles)`, define `unsigned char** array` as local variable instead as parameter and add `return array;` as last instruction in your function. Call `fileArray = fillArrays(fileSize,&noFiles)`.

Answer (score 1):

your `array` and `dataSize` are local to `fillArrays` function and
allocating memory to them inside `fillArrays` will not affect the arrays inside `main`.

```
// Allocates the memory to local variables
dataSize = (size_t *)malloc(nrows * sizeof(size_t));
array = (unsigned char**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(unsigned char *));
```

Hence you need to use pointer to pointer to `char*` for `fileArray` and
pointer to `size_t*` for `fileSize`.

*Your prototype will become as below.*

```
void fillArrays(unsigned char ***array, size_t **dataSize, int *nFiles)
```

*And you call the function as below.*

```
fillArrays(&fileArray,&fileSize, &noFiles);
```

**Sample code:**

```
void fillArrays(unsigned char ***array, size_t **dataSize, int *nFiles)
{
    printf("Calling fillArrays\n");
    int i, j, nrows;
    nrows = 3;
    *nFiles = nrows; // assuming no. of files to be read = 3

    *dataSize = (size_t *)malloc(nrows * sizeof(size_t));
    *array = (unsigned char**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(unsigned char *));

    (*dataSize)[0] = 4; // assuming file 1 contains 4 bytes
    (*dataSize)[1] = 3; // assuming file 2 contains 3 bytes
    (*dataSize)[2] = 1;// assuming file 3 contains 1 bytes

    //populating file data into a 2D array. Here for test purpose assuming each file has data = 0x03!!
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        (*array)[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc((*dataSize)[i] * sizeof(unsigned char));
        for(j = 0; j < (*dataSize)[i]; j++){
            printf("round %d %d\n", i,j);
            (*array)[i][j] = 0x03;
            printf("array [%d][%d]  = %02X\n ", i, j , (*array)[i][j]);
        }
        //array[i][dataSize[i]]= '\0';

    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char **fileArray;
    int noFiles = 0;
    size_t *fileSize;

    fillArrays(&fileArray,&fileSize, &noFiles);

    printf("Returned no. of files = %d\n", noFiles);
    printf("fileSize[0] = %lu\n", fileSize[0]);
    printf("fileSize[1] = %lu\n", fileSize[1]);
    printf("fileSize[2] = %lu\n", fileSize[2]);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <  noFiles; i++){
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        for (int j = 0; j <  fileSize[i]; j++){
            printf("Obtained data from file %d :  (fileArray [%d][%d])  = %02X\n ", i, i, j , fileArray[i][j]);
            //j++;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Alternate approach:**

I suggest you to not have pointer to pointer to `char*` as parameter instead you just return the filled array from `fillArrays` as below.

```
char** fillArrays(size_t **dataSize, int *nFiles)
{
    printf("Calling fillArrays\n");
    int i, j, nrows;
    char **array = NULL;
    nrows = 3;
    *nFiles = nrows; // assuming no. of files to be read = 3

    *dataSize = (size_t *)malloc(nrows * sizeof(size_t));
    array = (unsigned char**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(unsigned char *));

    (*dataSize)[0] = 4; // assuming file 1 contains 4 bytes
    (*dataSize)[1] = 3; // assuming file 2 contains 3 bytes
    (*dataSize)[2] = 1;// assuming file 3 contains 1 bytes

    //populating file data into a 2D array. Here for test purpose assuming each file has data = 0x03!!
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc((*dataSize)[i] * sizeof(unsigned char));
        for(j = 0; j < (*dataSize)[i]; j++){
            printf("round %d %d\n", i,j);
            array[i][j] = 0x03;
            printf("array [%d][%d]  = %02X\n ", i, j , array[i][j]);
        }
        //array[i][dataSize[i]]= '\0';

    }
  return array;
}
```

and you call the function as below.

```
fileArray = fillArrays(&fileSize, &noFiles);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However with so much pointers I am getting confused. Is there a better way to obtain this 2D array whose size gets known only by a call to fillArray?